# I looking for Containerfile or Dockerfile for container-registry.oracle.com/middleware/webtier image

Tags: oracle, dockerfile, podman

I am looking for Containerfile or Dockerfile for container-registry.oracle.com/middleware/webtier image. I need to see how Oracle builds its webtier container image. I have tried
***`podman inspect container-registry.oracle.com/middleware/webtier:latest`***
and it gives bunch of info but it is difficult for me to have whole pic. Please let me know where I can find this file.

Answer (score 1):

I found oracle repo on github and following is the URL for ohs 12.2.1.3.0 docker image dockerfile. https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/blob/main/OracleHTTPServer/dockerfiles/12.2.1.3.0/Dockerfile